# Regression of matrix-shaped output with sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, regression

I'd like to compute a regressor f() that fits y = f(X) where y has shape `(n_samples, n_attribs, n_outputs)` [i.e., n_outputs components/labels for different attributes] instead of the conventional shape `(n_samples, n_outputs)`

[MultiOutputRegressor in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) can handle the latter case. Is it capable of handling the former?

Obviously I could stack 3rd dimension columns, so that y has shape `n_samples, n_attribs x n_outputs`, but for commidity I'd like keep the original shape.

Is it still possible to perform a regression with sklearn? Should I look into other packages like Tensorflow/keras?

Thanks,
E CM

Answer (score 0):

If you check the help page:

> This strategy consists of fitting one regressor per target. This is a
> simple strategy for extending regressors that do not natively support
> multi-target regression.

This function fits a separate regressor for each column of your target, hopefully this is what you need, because from your description, "compute a regressor f() that fits y = f(X) ", it is not clear what regression you seek to use.

If there is an added dimension, you are restricted by this function, and if you do not stack it, i guess you make as many regressors as your third dimension, for example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

X = np.random.normal(0,1,(100,10))
y = np.random.normal(0,1,(100,2,2))

fits = [MultiOutputRegressor(Ridge(random_state=123)).fit(X, y[:,:,i]) for i in range(y.shape[2])]
```

And you can obtain the coefficients etc for each column by assessing each item in the list, for example:

```
fits[0].estimators_[0].coef_
```

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, thank you for taking time to answer my question. I have edited my post to hopefully make it clearer. I am interested in the case where `y = np.random.normal(0,1,(100,2,2))`.

Comment: yes.. i see it now. if you keep your shape, then what you end up with is a list of MultiOutputRegressor

Comment: Thanks! There isn't a buit-in solution in sklearn to handle that case, right? If I want to use this in a sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline, then I need to build a custom class that does the for loop on the 3rd axis of y. Agreed?

Comment: Yes. I would say so. Or you run your pipeline n times